# Error in rep("contr.dummy", l) : invalid 'times' argument rStudio error

Tags: r, vegan

Using the diversity function in the package vegan, I keep on getting the error "Error in rep("contr.dummy", l): invalid 'times' argument".
I have 2 data matrix's, one is the environmental data the other is the species counts for each of the samples. My computer has been acting up so I uninstalled rstudio and re-installed it and have been getting the error ever since.
It comes after I enter this code - Simpson <- diversity(itsdiv.df[,-120864], "simpson")

Comment: Looks like `I` might not be an integer, thus showing that it is an invalid value for the "times" argument. However, it will be difficult to know exactly what is happening without showing part of your data. You could try posting your data with the `dput` function.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, dput as follows: dput(itsdiv.df.t[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(c.0..28..0..0..64..11..0..0..1..8..0..4..431..7..4..12..1..118.. = c(0, 
28, 0, 0, 64), X.1 = c(17, 95, 3, 3, 48), X.2 = c(31, 66, 0, 
0, 40), X.3 = c(5, 17, 0, 0, 1), X.4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Could you add the complete code of what comes before `Simpson <- diversity(itsdiv.df[,-120864], "simpson")` and indicate the exact line where the error is occurring? That would help find the error.

Comment: The code before that line all works but here it is: itsdiv.df<-read.csv("counts.csv")
BASE<-read.csv("Contextual.csv")
itsdiv.df.t<-as.data.frame(t(itsdiv.df))
itsdiv.df.t<-as.data.frame(t(itsdiv.df))
colnames(itsdiv.df.t)<-its.names$ID
itsdiv.df.t$Sample_id<-substr(rownames(itsdiv.df.t),2,6)
itsdiv.df.t$Sample_id
itsdiv.df.t<-subset(itsdiv.df.t, Sample_id %in% BASE$Sample_id )
colnames(itsdiv.df.t)